# fail2ban: how to immediately ban those who attempt ssh userid logins

Tags: ssh, fail2ban

My OpenSSH server is set up to only allow key based logins. I get many attacks each day from bots trying to login using a userid and password. I have fail2ban configured and running already. How can I add a jail to immediately ban any IP address which attempts to login using a userid? No retrys, no timeouts, just instantly ban them, because by definition I know it's an attack.

Comment: If you disabled password authentication you can ignore those attempts. If you want to deny login based on userid/name configure ssh - http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/SSH_security#Users . Fail2ban is in this case unecessary as it bans by ip address.

Comment: I know the attacks are futile in my case, I'd just like to ban their IPs in case they try other attacks, and this seemed like an easy way to immediately know that the IP is evil.

Comment: So use iptables - http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/SSH_security#IPT really, your logs will always be noisy

Comment: From your same tutorial, it looks like `denyhosts` might be what I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: If you care to post your suggestion as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks, but, it really is best a comment as there are multiple options to secure your server, I merely pointed you to a set of pages I put up for my LUG and you made an informed decision. IMO education is best.

Comment: No one says you MUST use port 22 on your Internet-Facing IP address.   Pick a different port.   Use router 'port-forwarding' to forward port XXXX (external) to port 22 (internal).   Cuts out noise from nearly ALL script kiddies. (I get the occasional fool who wants to port scan the entire range.. but that can be hindered too.